# Webdriver instances - how to run multiple tests using one test base

Tags: java, selenium, testing, automation, testng

I'm learning automation testing in Java using Selenium and Testng. I've came across the issue that I cannot really solve, maybe someone here knows the solution.

I'm trying to run multiple tests from one class using multisession.xml. That works only if I add separate instance to each test, something like this:

`System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "src/main/resources/chromedriver.exe"); WebDriver driver; driver = new ChromeDriver();`

However, I want to use separate class (test base) that extends my class with tests in order to not duplicate code. If I do that, then my multisession.xml can only perform one test at the time and returns following exception:
*org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document*

My guess there is a problem with instances of webdriver. In my base initialization code looks like that:

```
public class TestBase {
public static WebDriver driver;
public static WebDriverWait wait;
public static Properties config;
public static Properties testdata;
```

Then setting up separate files with test data and initialization:

```
public static void initialization() {

    String url = config.getProperty("URL");
    String browser = config.getProperty("browser");
    String pageLoadTimeout = config.getProperty("pageLoadTimeout");
    String windowsMaximize = config.getProperty("windowsMaximize");
    String deleteAllCookies = config.getProperty("deleteAllCookies");
    String waitTimeout = config.getProperty("waitTimeout");


    switch (browser) {
        case "chrome":
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir") +
                    "/src/main/resources/chromedriver.exe");
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.addArguments("--incognito");

            driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

            break;
        case "firefox":
            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir") +
                    "/src/main/resources/geckodriver.exe");

            driver = new FirefoxDriver();

            break;
        case "msedge":
            System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir") +
                    "/src/main/resources/msedgedriver.exe");


            driver = new EdgeDriver();
            break;
        case "opera":
            System.setProperty("webdriver.opera.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir") +
                    "/src/main/resources/operadriver.exe");

            driver = new OperaDriver();
            break;
```

I will appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`StaleElementReferenceException` is thrown when the element you're looking for is no longer attached to the DOM. Most probably **you're trying to .findElement first, then DOM gets refreshed** and you're trying to access it. This often happens with parallel tests execution if your page-class instances with elements are not thread-safe.

Try to use:

```
object _lock = new object();

        lock (_lock)
        {
            //your driver initialization/login
        }
```

You should also define how many threads will be executing your tests by modifying `thread-count="5" parallel="methods"`

Comment: Hey man, thanks a lot for the reply! Though I don't think its the case since I don't use findelement method, at least not anywhere at the beginning. I think it's more related to fact that user has navigated away to another page - since when I want to launch 3 tests at once all 3 browser windows are opened, but only one continues with initialization and the other 2 are empty with just "data:," info returned.

Comment: @vandee the other 2 browser windows are opening empty because WebDriver is not thread-safe and there could be only 1 URL at a time navigated to, if you're not handling thread safety. Initialize a dictionary <int, string> and manage URLs separately for your threads. For example: public Dictionary<int, string> threadSafeUrls = new Dictionary<int, string>(); lock (_lock)
            {
                threadSafeUrls[Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId] = pageInstance.URL.Uri.AbsoluteUri;
            }

Comment: Thanks, it indeed seems to be an issue, I'm very glad I know now why that happened, though I will admit that I have no idea how to apply the given solution as InteliJ returns me "cannot resolve symbol" for string,_lock and CurrentThread/PageInstance. I'm still quite new to that :) Neverthless, thanks to you I know whats causing the problem and read a little about that. I will just stick to one instance per test for now.

Comment: @vandee, I should have mentioned that my answer applies to C# and Visual Studio. In case of Java the syntax is different: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html